# How to fix Class 'PDF' not found in laravel

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5

Encountered the following error in My Laravel app:

> FatalErrorException in CollaboPDFController.php line 14: Class 'PDF' not found

This is my **CollaboPDFController.php**:

```
<?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;

  use App\Http\Requests;
  use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
  use PDF;

  class CollaboPDFController extends Controller
  {
      public function getPDF(){
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('customer.customer'); //line 14
        return $pdf->download('customer.customer');
      }
      //
  }
```

How I can fix this?

Comment: what is your PDF class location?

Comment: laravel config/app.php

Comment: In your controller header, use this:

use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\PDF;

Answer (score 12):

You are using the wrong import. To use the PDF you want (probably laravel-dompdf) use:

```
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;
```

If you put `'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,` in your config/app.php you could also use:

```
use \PDF;
```

or

```
\PDF::loadView('customer.customer');
```

Comment: Did you run `composer install` after adding DomPDF to your composer.json? Or did you ran `composer require dompdf/dompdf`?

Answer (score 10):

First you have to require `DOMPDF` package

Step 1 :

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

Step 2 :  In ..\config\app.php

```
'providers' => [ 
  .....
  Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
],
'aliases' => [
  .....
 'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
]
```

Step 3 :

```
use \PDF;
```

Step 4 :

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.report');
return $pdf->stream('report.pdf', array('Attachment' => 0));
```

Comment: I am using lumen for my app's APIs. could you please suggest me how can i use Barryvdh\DomPDF in lumen api to generate and store pdf file. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I tried some of the examples above, but nothing worked.
However, I browsed the directory of the package located here:

> > project-folder>vendor>barryvdh>laravel-dompdf>src>Facade>Pdf.php
> > and I realized that the PDF alias created in the file >> app.php does not use the correct class.
> > So replace:

```html
'aliases' => [
  .....
 'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
]
```

by:

```html
'aliases' => [
  .....
 'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf::class,
]
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 4):

You can run following commands after installing dompdf and set service provider and aliases in this file config/app.php

**php artisan cache:clear** and **php artisan config:cache**

Answer (score 3):

Run the below command

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

Answer (score 1):

for those who tried all the solutions mentioned above and nothing works !
Try this it worked for me.
In the controller replace

```
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;
```

by

```
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf as PDF;
```

Answer (score 0):

finally got the solutions actually it was My domPDF installation problem I find out it this way

```
php artisan cache:clear
// and
php artisan config:cache
```

and install domPDF again

Comment: domPDF ki jinis ?

Answer (score 0):

**this is problem with cache config.php within bootstrap folder.**

shared hosting does not show full path of your [project folder]in shared hosting and if you want clear cache , you have to purchase their plugins. by the given solution you have no need to purchase any plugin or no need to clear / config cache of laravel 5.6 or more.

hit the URl in your browser it will give you error log. now oprn your error log and **copy the path from the error log**.

change all file paths in config.php of [your project folder ]/bootstrap/cache, [your project folder ]\bootstrap\cache or [your project folder ]* etc by the full path copied from error log like **/mnt/stor2-wc1-dfw1/411797/622471/[yourdomain]/web/content/[your project folder ]**