# Class 'PDF' not found - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to generate a PDF report in my application using the `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` package, but I'm receiving an error:

> Class 'PDF' not found

I have followed steps from previous answers to similar questions, but they don't seem to help me.

I added the following lines in my composer.json file:

```
"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.0",
"dompdf/dompdf": "0.8.0 as 0.6.2"
```

Then, I ran `composer update`. Afterwards, I included the following lines in my `config/app.php`:

```
Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
```

And finally, I ran the following commands in my terminal:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

**Controller**

```
Use PDF;

$pdf = PDF::loadView('app.feestdreportprint',compact('datas','rdata','stdinfo','institute'));
        return $pdf->stream('student-Payments.pdf');
```

But I am still getting the same error. What can I do to solve this issue? My laravel version is `5.4`.

Comment: Can you add the PHP code where you are using the class?

Comment: @Virginia, please check.  I have added that

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` perhaps.

Comment: Thanks, that helps! I saw this similar question a few minutes ago while trying to think together with you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41013731/how-to-fix-class-pdf-not-found-in-laravel Is there an answer that helps you, or an action you didn't try yet? (Or indeed what @bishop says)

Comment: @Virginia, well that's the link i followed and didn't help. And that is why i am created this question

Comment: @bishop giving me same error

Comment: Sorry to hear that those answers didn't help. However, it's always a good idea to also include such sources (including links) in your post. This prevents us from offering you solutions you already tried and saves us all time ;)

Answer (score 0):

please check if you put

```
'PDF' => Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyPdf::class,
```

as alias en app.php

I'm using other library maybe you can use it too.

Composer require:

```
 "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.1",
 "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "^0.4.0",

Provider: Barryvdh\Snappy\ServiceProvider::class,        
Alias: 'PDF' => Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyPdf::class,
```

In the controller:

```
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF;
```

Eg.

```
$pdf = App::make('snappy.pdf.wrapper');
$view = View::make('view::quote.pdf',['data' => $data]);
$pdf->loadHtml($view)->save($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have to put this lines in `config/app.php`.

```
'providers' => [Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class],
```

and

```
'aliases' => ['PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class]
```

and then you have to use this in your function its totally work for me
example

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('admin/order_pdf',compact('order_item','order','total_qty','total_ltr','total_weight'));

$pdf->save(storage_path().'_filename.pdf');

return $pdf->download('customers.pdf');
```